# How to play online MKV files with VLC without downloading them?

Tags: vlc-media-player, matroska

Is there anyway to play an [online MKV file](https://filesamples.com/formats/mkv) with VLC without having to download that file first?
If I click on "Open network stream", put the link of a MKV file there and click play, VLC only palys it after downloading the file.

Comment: this is expected behavior, and you will not be able to change it. the problem is on the server end, not the client.  can you explain why you would want to? the only reason I can think of is that you don't have enough disk space to store the whole file.

Comment: When I try to open a .mkv stream, e.g., https://filesamples.com/samples/video/mkv/sample_1280x720_surfing_with_audio.mkv , it starts playing **immediately** in VLC 3.0.17.4 (Vetinari -- praise be to Pratchett!).

Comment: @DrMoishePippik what is your internet connection speed? The file starts playing immediately for me too, but it also downloads in less than 1 second thanks to my internet bandwidth ~600Mb/s. So it's difficult to conclude if VLC has downloaded it before playing or not.

Comment: @PierU, though my internet speed is about half that, download took about 1 minute; apparently it was being throttled, or the server happened to be busy.